# Computing the integral of the sine integral remainder function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Define $\mathrm{si}(x) := \displaystyle\int_x^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\mathrm{d}t $ for all $x>0$. I have showed, by integration by parts, that this function has convergent integral over $\mathbf{R}^*_+$, but I now have trouble actually computing
$$ \int_0^\infty \mathrm{si}(x)\mathrm d x. $$
Anyone got any pointers ?

Update: For detail, I'll show's $\mathrm{si}$ integral converges. We have :

$$\mathrm{si}(x) = \cos(x)/x - \int_x^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}\mathrm d t = \frac{\cos(x)}{x} + \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} - 2\int_x^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{t^3}\mathrm d t. $$
The second integral is smaller than the integral of $1/t^3$ over the same interval, which is $1/2x^2$. Thus
$$ \mathrm{si}(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}x + \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \frac{\cos(x)}x + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right). $$

Comment: Due to Mathematica, it's $1$.

Comment: What about a manual proof ?

Comment: BTW, how do you show by integration by parts that $(\sin t)/t$ is integrable over $\mathbb R^+$?

Comment: I meant for $\mathrm{Si}$, but I'll show both: let $x$ be a strictly positive real number. Then,
$\int_1^x \sin(t)/t \mathrm d t = \cos(x)/x - \cos(1) - \int_1^x \cos(t)/t^2\mathrm d t$. The second integral converges, the first terms has limit $0$ as $x\to \infty$, thus the integral of $\sin(t)/t$ converges.

Comment: Well, $\int_{-x}^x t\,dt = 0$. Is $t\mapsto t$ integrable over $\mathbb R$? You have to show that the **absolute value** of the integrand is integrable, which means that you will have to split the integral.

Comment: Whoops, I said integrable whilst I mean the integral converges. I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrating by parts, $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{b} \left(\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt \right) \, dx &=  x \left( \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt \right)\Bigg|^{b}_{0}+ \int_{0}^{b} \sin(x) \, dx \\ &= b \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt  -\cos(b) + 1 . \end{align}$$

But you showed that  $\int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt \sim \frac{\cos b}{b} + \frac{\sin b}{b^{2}} $ as $b \to \infty$.

So as $b \to \infty$, $b \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt  -\cos(b)$ tends to zero, showing that the integral does indeed evaluate to $1$.

Strangely, Wolfram Alpha (unlike Mathematica) says that the integral doesn't converge.  But if you make the upper limit very large, it returns a value very close to $1$.

Answer (score -2):

$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{Si}(x)\mathrm dx$
$\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \mathrm{\frac{sint}{t}}\mathrm dtdx$

Then by changing the order of integration we get

$\int_0^\infty \int_0^t \mathrm{\frac{sint}{t}}\mathrm dxdt$

$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{sinx}\mathrm dx$

Which diverges

Comment: Does the function verify the conditions for Fubini's theorem ?